# Docker compose ¿caching? env variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm experiencing very strange behaviour with docker-compose. I have a repository configured to work with `docker swarm` for production and `docker-compose` for development. Swarm is working OK in production, but `docker-compose` is having strange behaviour.

Specifically, I'm defining build arguments with parameter substitution, like this

```
build:
  context: .
  args:
    - APP_DIRECTORY=${APP_DIRECTORY:-/srv/app}
    - APP_ENV=${APP_ENV:-dev}
```

When `APP_ENV` is not defined or is empty, it should take the value `dev`. This was working fine, but now it's taking the value `prod` when the variable is not defined. I rebooted, cleared all envrionment variables, even removed `docker-compose` and installed it again, and `APP_ENV` is still being assinged `prod`. Is there some sort of caching done by compose that I'm not being aware of?

Another strange behaviuor, is that `docker-compose` is passing proxy-related envionment variables to the container. Those variables are not specified on the compose file, and they are not even present  on the host. Again, is there some soer of caching taking place? And why is `docker-compose` passing env variables that I didn't ask for to the container?

Comment: Are you specifically requesting `docker-compose up --build`?  I think Compose won't rebuild an image unless specifically requested.  (If this is deploy-time configuration, an environment variable rather than a build argument might be more appropriate.)

Comment: Not even that, I'm doing `docker-compose build` first, and the image is built with incorrect build arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was making a stupding mistake, I had a `.env` file in the same directory, and `docker-compose` was reading the variables from the file.